Limit of $\sqrt[n]{2-x_n}$
Let $x_n$ be the real positive root of equation: $$x^n=x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\ldots+x+1$$
Find $\lim{(2-x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$
Here is what I tried:
Initial:
$$x^n > 1 \Rightarrow x > 1$$
It is easy to prove that the equation have only one real postive root
Rewrite the equation as:
$$x_n = \frac{x^n-1}{x-1} \Leftrightarrow x^{n+1}-2x^{n}+1 = 0$$
If $x \geq 2$:
$$x^{n}(x-2) + 1 \geq 1 >0$$
which is a contradiction, thus $x <2$
So $2-x_n>0$
Then $$(2-x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}>0$$
Rewrite the equation as:
$$2-x_n = \frac{1}{x_n^n} \Rightarrow (2-x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{x_n}$$
I got stuck here, can anyone help me continue this, thanks!

Let $f_n(x)=x^{n+1}-2x^n+1=(x-2)x^n+1$ and let $x_{\varepsilon}=2-\varepsilon$ by fixed. Then, $f_n(x_{\varepsilon})$ tends to $-\infty$ and $f_n(2)=1$, so by Bolzano's theorem, for big enough $n$, there is a root between them. Therefore $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ and $n>N(\varepsilon)$, $x_\varepsilon < x_n < 2$

Let $x=2-\epsilon$ and expand as a series. You will have bounds for $\epsilon$

Define $f(x) = x^n(2-x)$ for $x\in (1,2)$ and $n \ge 1$. Then
$$f'(x)=-(n+1)x^{n-1}\left(x-\underbrace{\frac{2n}{n-1}}_{>2} \right) >0$$
So, $f(x)$ is increasing in function of $x$.

As you already proved, $x_n \in (1,2)$. Then
$$1 = -\left(x_{n+1}\right)^{n+2} + 2\left(x_{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=
\color{red}{\underbrace{\left(x_{n+1}\right)^{n+1} \left(2-x_{n+1}  \right)}_{=f(x_{n+1})}> \underbrace{\left(x_{n+1}\right)^{n} \left(2-x_{n+1}  \right)}_{=f(x_n)} }
$$
As $f$ is increasing, we deduce that $x_{n+1}>x_n$.
The sequence $(x_n)$ is increasing and bounded by $2$, so it converges to a limit $l>1$. We have:
$$x_n = 2+ \frac{1}{x_n^{n+1}} \implies \lim x_n = 2 + \underbrace{\lim_{n+\infty}\frac{1}{x_n^{n+1}}}_{\xrightarrow{n \to \infty}0} = 2$$

And as you already proved $(2-x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{1}{x_n}$, we deduce that
$$\color{red}{\lim_{n\infty}(2-x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}} =\lim_{n\infty}\frac{1}{x_n} = \frac{1}{2}}$$

From this post: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1333681p7204771
I think $\lim (2-x_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ should be $0$

@LụcTrườngPhát why do you think the limit of this expression is $0$? The question in the link is exactly as yours, no additional info.

I don't understand the last line why $\lim = 0.5$, can you explain more please, thank you a lot! @NN2

@LụcTrườngPhát it’s because $x_n \to 2$ (proven in the previous step) so $1/x_n \to 1/2$
